# Change password hashing (one-way encryption) function

Tags: mysql, hash, import

I have no idea if this is possible.

I have a mysql database that has passwords encrypted with Whirpool and I wondering if it's is possible to import them all to PBKDF2hash, and how?

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Well i have a db that has passwords stored with whirpool i believe, and i want to export them to other will be in PBKDF2, because I need to change the software that auth my users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible (short of brute-force) unless you have the plaintext, unhashed, passwords available.